# Как добавить кнопку под товар Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, корзина

Как вставить кнопку "добавить в корзину" непосредственно под товаром в витрине woocommerce?

Тема Divi.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что такое "непосредственно под товаром". Под фотографией? Над названием? Поменять местами кнопку и цену? Или кнопки сейчас вообще не видно?

Comment: Кнопка "Добавить в корзину" есть в карточке товара. Нужно добавить кнопку под товар в категории товаров.

Comment: Думал, что кнопку по умолчанию видно, если только товар продаётся. Напишите, какая установлена тема, и добавьте  в вопрос скриншот с отсутствующей кнопкой, скриншот с кнопкой в карточке товара и ссылку на сайт.

Comment: Добавил скрин, тема Divi. Сайт kartina-color.ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл рулит: [divi woocommerce add to cart button](https://www.google.ru/search?q=divi%20woocommerce%20add%20to%20cart%20button).

Первый вариант — добавить в `functions.php` своей темы строку:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
```

Второй вариант — завернуть эту строку в функцию и привязать её к [after_setup_theme](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/after_setup_theme):

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'lets_add_cart_button' );
function lets_add_cart_button () {
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 20 );
}
```

PS: Лучше редактировать не саму тему, а дочернюю к ней.

PPS: Удобная [карта хуков на странице магазина](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/).

Comment: Спасибо большое, кнопка появилась, а как сделать чтобы она вела себя также как кнопка в карточке товара? Я про сообщении добавлении товара в корзину.

Comment: @Алексей Сделайте новый вопрос об этом. И добавьте картинку, каким и где оно должно быть.